# Read HDF5 files compressed with SZIP in Matlab

Tags: matlab, compression, hdf5

I have some results generated from a legacy Fortran program, that write compressed dataset utilizing SZIP compression. I would like to read them in matlab. Unfortunately the matlab HDF5 does not support SZIP compression.
Does any of you have any idea on how to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance
AR